# preventing calculations in variables during a select statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a dynamic query based upon selections passed to a script. Example:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM machinekaart 
INNER JOIN afleveradressen ON afleveradressen.raaid = mkrraaid 
INNER JOIN kontaktpersonen ON kontaktpersonen.rkpraaid = mkrraaid   
WHERE mkrrid != '' " ;

if($_SESSION['oud'])
    $qry .= "  AND mkrvo < " . $cur_jaar_maand;
```

Field mkrvo is a text field, and can contain yyyy-mm besides other values.

e.g. when the varable $cur_maand_jaar contains '2015-01' the selection will be everything lower than 2014

How can I stop this from happening and selecting everything lower than '2015-01' ??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest quoting that variable, so the values are taken literally:

```
if($_SESSION['oud'])
    $qry .= "  AND mkrvo < '" . $cur_jaar_maand . "'";
```

Better than that, please use PDO so you can use bindings, it's safer and best optimized.

Eg.

```
if($_SESSION['oud'])
    $qry .= "  AND mkrvo < ?";

// build your PDO Connection $myPdoConnection ...

$pdoStatement = $myPdoConnection->prepare($qry);

$pdoStatement->execute(array($cur_jaar_maand));
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the SQL text, enclose the string literal in single quotes, so it's *not* evaluated as a numeric expression.

Evaluated in a numeric context: `2015-01` produces a value of `2014`.

But **`'2015-01'`** is evaluated as a string literal.

(If the string literal is evaluated in a numeric context (e.g. `'2015-01' + 0`) the string will evaluate to a numeric value of `2015`.)

---

The code you posted appears to be vulnerable to **SQL Injection**.

Consider what SQL text is generated when `$cur_jaar_maand` happens to evaluate to **`0 OR 1=1 --`**.

A much better pattern is to make use of **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.